# Как переместить объект в python (Pygame)

Tags: python, разработка-игр, объекты, pygame

```
def _cheсk_events(self):
        """Реагировать на нажимание клавиш и мыши"""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    #Перемистить корабль вправо
                    self.x = self.ship.rect.pop(0)
                    self.ship.rect.x += 1
                    self.ship.rect.append(0,x)
```

Когда я запускаю код пишет трейсбек:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Пайтон АртемЧ\My_work\Alien_Invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 59, in <module>
    ai.run_game()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Пайтон АртемЧ\My_work\Alien_Invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 53, in run_game
    self._cheсk_events()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Пайтон АртемЧ\My_work\Alien_Invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 36, in _cheсk_events
    self.ship.rect.x += 1
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Полный код:

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings

from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    """ Класс всей игры """

    def __init__(self):
        """Атрибуты """
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width,
                                               self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')

        self.ship = Ship(self)

        # цвет фона
        self.rgb = (self.settings.rgb_color)
        

    def _cheсk_events(self):
        """Реагировать на нажимание клавиш и мыши"""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    #Перемистить корабль вправо
                    self.x = self.ship.rect.pop(0)
                    self.ship.rect.x += 1
                    self.ship.rect.append(0,x)
                    
                    
                                        
    def _update_screen(self):
        """Обновить экран и нарисовать его"""       
        self.screen.fill(self.rgb)
        self.ship.blitme()

        pygame.display.flip()
        

    def run_game(self):
        """ Начать игру """
        
        while True:
            self._cheсk_events()
            self._update_screen()
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, чинить ваш код нужно примерно так (в экземпляре класса `AlienInvasion` переменная `self.x` совершенно не нужна, для вычислений достаточно временной локальной переменной `x`):

```
x = self.ship.rect.pop(0)
x += 1
self.ship.rect.append(0,x)
```

Я только не понял, зачем всё так сложно сделано: вынуть элемент из списка, поменять, вставить обратно. Можно же поменять элемент прямо внутри списка:

```
self.ship.rect[0] += 1
```

Ещё лучше было бы, если бы `rect` был не списком, а объектом с "говорящими" полями, вроде того же `.x`, чтобы не обращаться к списку по непонятным индексам, а обращаться к этим понятным полям, но пока хотя бы так.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!